# Emacs/AucTeX: can LaTeX-math-list read a macro that requires input?

Tags: math-mode, emacs, auctex

I wanted to make a macro that inserts \left \right delimiters, but I wanted to write it only once and have different bindings pass different delimiters. To wit, I wanted to add the following code:

```
(setq LaTeX-math-list (quote ( ("C-(" (LaTeX-my-leftright "(" ")") "" nil)
    ("C-{" (LaTeX-my-leftright "\{" "\}") "" nil)
    )))
```

Where the program does the following:

```
(defun LaTeX-my-leftright (charopen charclose)
"Inserts the pattern '\leftC  \rightD' where C is the open input char and D the closed, and places the cursor in the center."
    (interactive)
    (setq out1 (concat "\\left" charopen " "))
    (setq out2 (concat " \\right" charclose))
    (insert out1)
    (push-mark)
    (insert out2)
    (exchange-point-and-mark)
)
```

However, when I run this by pressing ` and then C-( I get a

> Wrong type argument: commandp (LaTeX-my-leftright "(" ")")

error message.

Does anyone know what the correct syntax is here, or if this is even possible with LaTeX-math-list? I've looked a little bit at the latex.el file and I'm beginning to think the answer is no, but maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `value` slot needs to be a 0-argument interactive function not an evaluated expression, also `\{` needs an extra level of `\` quoting to get the backslash into the lisp string.

This seems to work

```
(setq LaTeX-math-list (quote ( 
    ("C-(" (lambda ()(interactive)(LaTeX-my-leftright "(" ")")) "" nil)
    ("C-{" (lambda ()(interactive)(LaTeX-my-leftright "\\{" "\\}")) "" nil)
    )))
```